# Rotate matrix rings first line is getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

In this code I had getting error the below error

```
Enter M: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    M = int(input("Enter M: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 4'
```

The Question is below

Given a matrix of order M*N and a value K, write a program to rotate each ring of the matrix clockwise by K elements. If in any ring has less than or equal to K elements, then don’t rotate that ring.

Input

The first line of input will be two space-separated integers, denoting the M and N.
The next M lines will contain N space-separated integers.
The next line will contain an integer, denoting K.

Output

The output should be M*N matrix by rotating the matrix by K elements.

Explanation

For example, if the given M and N are 4 and 4 respectively. If the matrix elements are
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
If the given K is 3. Rotate each ring of the matrix by 3 elements.
In the above matrix, the elements (1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 9, 5) is a ring, similarly, the elements (6, 7, 11, 10) will make a ring.
Therefore, by rotating each ring in clockwise direction by 3 elements will give (13, 9, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 15, 14) and (10, 6, 7, 11). So the output should be
13 9 5 1
14 7 11 2
15 6 10 3
16 12 8 4

The code is below

```
M = int(input("Enter M: "))
N = int(input("Enter N: "))
 
A = [[0]*N for x in range(M)]
for i in range(0, M):
    for j in range(0, N):
        A[i][j] = int(input())
 
K = int(input("Enter K: "))
Ring = (min(M, N) + 1) // 2
 
count = 0
r = 0
d = 0
l = 0
u = 0
 
for i in range(Ring):
    size = 2*(M-2*i) + 2*(N-2*i) - 4
    if M-2*i == 1:
        size = N-2*i
    if N-2*i == 1:
        size = M-2*i
    if size == 0:
        size = 1
    if size <= K:
        continue
    B = [0] * size
    startX = i
    startY = i
    for r in range(i, N-i):
        B[count] = A[startX][r]
        count += 1
    for d in range(startY + 1, M-i):
        B[count] = A[d][r]
        count += 1
    l = r - 1
    if M-(2*i) > 1 and N-(2*i) > 1:
        while l >= i:
            B[count] = A[d][l]
            count += 1
            l -= 1
        u = d - 1
        while u >= i + 1:
            B[count] = A[u][l+1]
            count += 1
            u -= 1
    for t in range(K):
        temp = B[size - 1]
        j = size - 1
        while j != 0:
            B[j] = B[j-1]
            j -= 1
        B[0] = temp
    
    count = 0
    r = 0
    d = 0
    l = 0
    u = 0
 
    for r in range(i, N-i):
        A[startX][r] = B[count]
        count += 1
    for d in range(startY + 1, M-i):
        A[d][r] = B[count]
        count += 1
    l = r - 1
    if M-(2*i) > 1 and N-(2*i) > 1:
        while l >= i:
            A[d][l] = B[count]
            count += 1
            l -= 1
        u = d - 1
        while u >= i + 1:
            A[u][l+1] = B[count]
            count += 1
            u -= 1
    
    count = 0
    r = 0
    d = 0
    l = 0
    u = 0
 
print("")
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        print(A[i][j], end = "\t")
    print("")
```

And also not getting expected Test case output, the test cases are

```
Test case 1
Input
4 4
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
3
Output
13 9 5 1
14 7 11 2
15 6 10 3
16 12 8 4
Test case 2
Input
3 4
1 2 3 4
10 11 12 5
9 8 7 6
2
Output
9 10 1 2
8 11 12 3
7 6 5 4
```

Please help me anybody python expert.

Comment: Anybody please help me

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to enter two numbers at once through a space instead of entering one at a time through Enter. To enter two numbers with one Input, you can do this: `M,N = [int(x) for x in input("Enter M N: ").split(' ')]`

Comment: Sir problem not solved sir

Comment: please help me sir

Comment: Алексей Р sir please help me sir

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the problem is. At the beginning of your post, you indicated that the problem is a string-to-number conversion error. Is it solved?

Comment: No sir not solved sir

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WiyF9wCvaKiC9KtX0hcoqeXfFq3seuAy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sir the above link contains question  sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for enter data (section Input of the question):

```
M, N = [int(x) for x in input("Enter M N: ").split(' ')]
nums = []
for i in range(0, M):
    nums.append([int(x) for x in input(f"Enter {i} row with {N} space-separated integers: ").split(' ')])
K = input("Enter integer K: ")

print(f"You entered:\nM={M},N={N}")
print(f"Lists of entered space-separated integers is:\n{nums}")
print(f"K={K}")
```

> Output

```
Enter M N: 3 3
Enter 0 row with 3 space-separated integers: 1 2 3
Enter 1 row with 3 space-separated integers: 4 5 6
Enter 2 row with 3 space-separated integers: 7 8 9
Enter integer K: 10
You entered:
M=3,N=3
Lists of entered space-separated integers is:
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
K=10
```